# Why is the digest of a data.frame changed after the use of dplyr in R?

Tags: r, compare, dplyr, digest

I assume that if I have 2 identical data.frames, the R digest function should return the same result. Consider these two data frames.

```
library(digest)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(a =1:5, b=11:15)
df2 <-  df1 %>% 
        mutate(c=b-1) %>% 
        select(-c)
```

Both data.frames are identical when printed,

```
> df1
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1    11
2     2    12
3     3    13
4     4    14
5     5    15
```

or compared:

```
> df1 ==df2
        a    b
[1,] TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE
```

However, the digest function returns different results:

```
> digest(df1)
[1] "4f82aa1035792a0acf304242ce6ad3ec"
> digest(df2)
[1] "3b7e697af67e8e36ba9b59aef69db304"
```

I would expect the digest function to result in the same result!!
Is there a better way to compare identical data.frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why the `digest` is differing between the two. It is important to note, however, that this does not just happen with `dplyr`

```
df3 <- df1
df3$c <- 1
df3 <- df3[ ,-3]

digest(df3)
```

returns a third unique value

```
75f29cee80971220081372627632689f
```

Though it is interesting to note that the `digest` of `df4 <- df1[,1:2]` is the same. I can even generate that same hash from both `df1` and `df2` with:

```
digest(df1[,1:2])
digest(df2[,1:2])
```

and a different (shared) hash of "f111f4b3d65b8bc2569a4b79a821a6d8" with

```
digest(as.data.frame(df1[,1:2]))
digest(as.data.frame(df2[,1:2]))
```

It must have something to do with how R handles the creation of the variable as it stores it in memory. My understanding is that `digest` is not giving a hash on the values *within* the variable but rather a hash of the variable itself. So, you may need to add a step that generates the variable in the same manner to get the hashes to agree.

However, if you are looking for a different way to compare, I will suggest `all_equal` from `dplyr`

```
all_equal(df1, df2)
```

returns `TRUE` and allows some handling of edge cases that might be nice (e.g., by default it doesn't care if the rows or columns are rearranged). If your goal is just to check the congruence of two datasets, this is likely a "better" way than fighting with `digest`

Comment: Thank you! The `all_equal()` should do the trick for now!  The data.frame slicing probably helps because the attribute order is changed as Axeman pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about `digest`, but the order of the `attributes` has changed, perhaps because `names` got updated last:

```
attributes(df1)
```

> ```
> $names
> [1] "a" "b"
>
> $class
> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
>
> $row.names
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

```
attributes(df2)
```

> ```
> $class
> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
>
> $row.names
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
>
> $names
> [1] "a" "b"
> ```

Comment: This is interesting! Mark Peterson (other answer) got the same hash after slicing the data.frames. This probably got the attributes into the same order! Thank you!